# Replace All Occurrences In A String Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a string of data..

```
This is a template body for  &lt&ltApproved&gt&gt &lt&ltSubmitted&gt&gt
```

I want to replace "&lt" with "<<" and "&gt" with ">>"

To replace "&lt" I wrote this code..

```
 var body = $('#txtHSliderl').val().replace("&lt", "<<");
```

But it only seems to replace the first occurrence..

```
This is a template body for  <<&ltApproved&gt&gt &lt&ltSubmitted&gt&gt
```

How do I replace all occurrences?

Comment: Are you generating those `&lt` and `&gt`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var body = $('#txtHSliderl').val().replace(/&lt/g, "<<");
```

Comment: global, it means it will match the regular expression multiple times rather than just the first occurence.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a regular expression, so that you can specify the global (g) flag:

```
 var body = $('#txtHSliderl').val().replace(/&lt/g, "<<");
```

Answer (score 1):

just use g  like as below

```
 var body = $('#txtHSliderl').val().replace(/&lt/g, "<<").replace(/&gt/g, ">>");
```

as you want to replace woth &lt and &gt in your value so you have to applied mathod twice

`g` is used in this function i.e. replace to replace all occurance of given string instace.