# How to replace all existence of chars from string in jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, string, replace

I want to replace all existence of chars from a string, but it is not working. here is my code:

```
 $.each(jsonArray, function (fromString, jtm) {
   // tempString = tempString.replace(jtm.from, jtm.to)
   tempString = tempString.replaceAll(jtm.from, jtm.to);
 });
```

I checked to use global to replace all as [Told in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345628/replace-all-occurances-in-a-string-jquery) but i am not getting how i can implement in my code.

Please help me.

Comment: `tempString = tempString.replace(new RegExp(jtm.from,'g'), jtm.to)`

Comment: `tempString = tempString.replace(new RegExp(jtm.from.replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g, '\\$&'),'g'), jtm.to)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript there is no method like `replaceAll()`, to remove all occurrence you need to use regex with global flag.

```
tempString = tempString.replace(new RegExp(jtm.from,'g'), jtm.to);
```

---

In case string contains characters which have special meaning in regex then escape them first.

```
tempString = tempString.replace(new RegExp(jtm.from.replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g, '\\$&'),'g'), jtm.to)
```

Refer : [Converting user input string to regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression)